# c++ forward namespace declaration in parameter

Tags: c++, namespaces

I got a class declared within a namespace:

```
namespace PixelViewer
{
  class FBO
  { ... }
}
```

and I want to use it as parameter in another class method as follows:

Model.h

```
class ShaderProgram;
class PixelViewer::FBO;

class Model
{
 void Model::render(ShaderProgram& shaderProgram, PixelViewer::FBO& fbo)
}
```

Model.cxx

```
#include "../FBO.h"
#include "../ShaderProgram/ShaderProgram.h"

void Model::render(ShaderProgram& shaderProgram, PixelViewer::FBO& fbo)
```

However, I'm getting the folllowing errors:

```
'PixelViewer' is not a class or namespace name

'FBO' uses undefined class PixelViewer

use of undefined type 'PixelViewer'
```

Any ideas on what I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax is not valid since `PixelViewer` could be both a namespace or a class name. So the syntax is disallowed:

```
class PixelViewer::FBO; // disallowed
```

Instead, just add the forward declaration in the corresponding namespace:

```
namespace PixelViewer {
    class FBO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to do a forward declare in the namespace:

```
namespace PixelViewer
{
    class FBO;
}
```

Remember that it could be a namespace, a class or a struct, so the compiler must know which one it's supposed to use internally.